# Stating two if statements in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have run in to a problem at the moment on trying to solve how I would go about writing a section of my games model.

I currently have the following in my def index section of the model:

```
def index
  games_relation = case params[:console].present?
    when true then Game.where(:console => params[:console])
    else Game
  end
  @games = games_relation.search(params[:search])
end
```

Now that works fine but I want to add in another section which looks at username so it includes the following:

```
user_relation = case params[:username].present?
  when true then User.where("username LIKE ?", "#{params[:username]}%")
  else User
end
```

Now I imagine I put in the two loops in to the index but how would I go about doing the @games line?

I have tried something like the following but no luck:

```
def index
  games_relation = case params[:console].present?
    when true then Game.where(:console => params[:console])
    else Game
  end

  name_relation = case params[:game_name].present?
    when true then Game.where("game_name LIKE ?", "#{params[:game_name]}%")
    else Game
  end

  @games = name_relation.games_relation.search(params[:search])
end
```

I currently have it calling the games_relation but how would I do it so that it calls games_relation and the user_relation?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your problem, but one thing I can tell for sure: you should not use case statement if you have only two options. Use `if ... else` instead.

Comment: Hey I just updated my question to give an idea of what I have tried and what I am attempting to do.

Comment: if you can just describe the relation between games and users then i'll draw this up for you in 2 secs.

Comment: Hey, sorry that was a mistake, copied in the wrong code, I have now updated the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1) this is the method of least code:

```
@games = Game
@games = @games.where("game_name LIKE ?", "#{params[:game_name]}%") if params[:game_name].present?
@games = @games.where("console = ?", params[:console]) if params[:console].present?
```

however that will result in 3 queries.

Option 2) 1 query, more code:

```
@games = if params[:game_name].present? && params[:console].present?
  Game.where("console = ? AND game_name LIKE ?", params[:console], "#{params[:game_name]}%")
elsif params[:game_name].present? && !params[:console].present?
  Game.where("game_name LIKE ?", "#{params[:game_name]}%")
elsif !params[:game_name].present? && params[:console].present?
  Game.where("console = ?", params[:console])
else
  Game
end
```

Comment: Yep, that answered my question. Cheers for that :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using case statements for true or false conditions which makes hard to read the code, you could do something like this:

```
games_relation = params[:console].present? ? Game.where(:console => params[:console]) : Game
```

And

```
user_relation = params[:game_name].present? ? User.where("game_name LIKE ?", "#{params[:game_name]}%") : User
```

Thats for the conditions. But I guess from your code that your models are something like this:

user:

```
has_many :games
```

game:

```
belongs_to :user
```

So you could do it this way:

```
def index
  @games = User.games

  @games = @games.where(:console => params[:console]) if params[:console].present?

  @games = @games.where("game_name LIKE ?", "#{params[:game_name]}%") if params[:game_name].present?

  @games
end
```

Comment: This answered my question also. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Like KL-7 advises, use if/else. The purpose of case is when you have multiple if's. You have one or two.

If you need to do complexer searches, I'd suggest you use https://github.com/ernie/meta_search. You just have to pass in the search params (properly named key/values) and it takes care for you.